# Where do program-created files end up in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

A Java program I ran created a new file using the `BufferedWriter` class. However, I can't figure out where Eclipse stored this file in my project. What is the default path?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the program's working directory (where files are saved if you don't specify the path) is the project directory.

You may need to refresh the project (right click -> Refresh) to make the files appear in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you passed into BufferedWriter's constructor when you used it. You probably passed in something like a FileWriter, which in turn needed a pathname specified.

If you didn't specify an absolute path, the file is created relative to the project location, which you can find if you click on Project > Properties and look at the Location.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a "index.txt" file, it will be in the root folder of your eclipse project workspace as index.txt